# How to make add-in manifest.xml for excel?

Tags: excel, outlook-addin, add-in, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm new to excel programming.
I need to make something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdFTT.png) (new tab on nav-bar and a few buttons).

The main question is how to create a new tab (like FWO-Office-Addins on picture). Thx for help !

Comment: please add approaches you have attempted into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are interested in add-in commands with a custom ribbon tab. For example, the following examples show how to use the `ExtensionPoint` element with `PrimaryCommandSurface` attribute value, and the child elements that should be used with each:

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
  <CustomTab id="Contoso Tab">
  <!-- If you want to use a default tab that comes with Office, remove the above CustomTab element, and then uncomment the following OfficeTab element -->
  <!-- <OfficeTab id="TabData"> -->
    <Label resid="residLabel4" />
    <Group id="Group1Id12">
      <Label resid="residLabel4" />
      <Icon>
        <bt:Image size="16" resid="icon1_32x32" />
        <bt:Image size="32" resid="icon1_32x32" />
        <bt:Image size="80" resid="icon1_32x32" />
      </Icon>
      <Tooltip resid="residToolTip" />
      <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Button1Id1">

        <!-- information about the control -->
      </Control>
      <!-- other controls, as needed -->
    </Group>
  </CustomTab>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

Read more about that in the [Add-in commands for Excel, PowerPoint, and Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) article.

Comment: hello, thx for answer, i was trying this, but it wasnt working, then a added a: 
<bt:ShortStrings>
    <bt:String id="myId" DefaultValue="MyName"/>
</bt:ShortStrings> 
in the end of manifest.xml and now its working !